# How can i keep original index when doing outer merge and dropping rows?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a big df (rates) that contains all information, then I have a second dataframe (aig_df) that contains a couple of rows of the first one.

I need to get a 3rd dataframe that is basically the big one (rates) without the rows on the second one (aig_df), but I need to keep the corresponding indices of the rows that results of rates without aig_df.

With the code I have now, I can get the 3rd dataframe with all the information needed but with int index and I need the index corresponding to each row (Index = Stock Ticker).

```
rates = pd.read_sql("SELECT Ticker, Carrier, Product, Name, CDSC,StrategyTerm,ParRate,Spread,Fee,Cap FROM ProductRates ", conn).set_index('Ticker')

aig_df = rates.query('Product == "X5 Advantage AnnuitySM"')

competitors_df = pd.merge(rates, aig_df[['Carrier', 'Product', 'Name','CDSC','StrategyTerm','ParRate','Spread','Fee','Cap']],indicator=True,
                          how='outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge',axis=1)
```

¿Is there any way to do what I need?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Can you provide ax example? A simple input, and the desired output

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you don't need a merge to do what you want:

```
result = rates[rates["Product"] != "X5 Advantage AnnuitySM"]
```

Comment: Oh I understand your point, but there are some cases where that filter is not enough because I do need some rates["Product"] != "X5 Advantage AnnuitySM"] (not this example case but other df I filter by name & other variable, so I would need some rates["Product"] != "X5 Advantage AnnuitySM"] that has for example a 'Spread' variable >0.

Comment: @ArturoM Please improve your question then, and add an example to clarify things (use fake columns such as 'A', 'B', 'C' etc)

Comment: I actually think your answer works, I can do the same boolean logic but with more conditions, thanks.